# How to create empty object of Payment class in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, payment, paypal, object

I have to create Payment object in

`vendor/magento/module-paypal/Plugin/OrderCanInvoice.php`

Is it `$foo = new Payment()` ?

It gives me an error

`Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Payment::__construct()`

How to create an object of `Payment` class

> vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Payment.php

Answer (score 1):

You cannot Object like `$foo = new Payment()` way.

`OrderCanInvoice.php` has some required the class at[`__construct`](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/ddf42caaf25311f10b23b95a92746f99943e045e/app/code/Magento/Sales/Model/Order/Payment.php#L165) function, So you have provided this parameter with `Payment()`.

Or at magento2, if you want to create an object of a class then you need to use injection  like:

```
private $orderPayment;
public function __construct(
 \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Payment $orderPayment
)
{
// Create Object of vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Payment.php
  $this->orderPayment = $orderPayment;  
}
```

Also don't understand why you want to create Payment object of `vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Payment.php` in `vendor/magento/module-paypal/Plugin/OrderCanInvoice.php`, where the object is already exited at  `$order->getPayment()`.